# How can i solve this unity android build error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I could build it just 5 miniute ago and only thing changed was defult oriantation.
but now it gives me an error. so how can i solve this?
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
C:/Program

```
Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.3f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx98304m" "assembleRelease"
    
stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key 060114 from store "C:\Users\JU\New Unity Projectg\user.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key 060114 from store "C:\Users\JU\New Unity Projectg\user.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

This looks like it's about Keystore. Check that password to that "user" Keystore is correct.